# Score storage in file: program crashes on run in c

Tags: c

I want to create a text file using C which would keep on adding score every time the code is run without deleting the last record. Unfortunately, when I run the code, All it does is run the `printf` statement and create a file `score.txt`, but doesn't write anything into it, instead it just crashes.

Here's the code:

```
int main()    
{
    FILE *score;
    score = fopen("score.txt", "w");
    fclose(score);
    int s;
    char n;
    printf("You got a high score!\nPlease enter score: ");
    scanf("%d", &s);
    printf("\nPlease enter your name: ");
    scanf("%s", &n);
    fprintf(score,"%d", s);
    fprintf(score,"%d", n);
    printf("\nData Stored into score.txt\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why `fclose(score);` after just opening file? also `n` is `char` and u r using it as string.

Comment: In the 2nd line you opened a file, and in the next line you closed it. Why?

Comment: Why are you trying to squash a whole input string into one char?  I assure you that it will not work.

Comment: All in all, this is a train wreck.

Comment: Also, learn how to use a debugger, so you can find out which line/s crash or generate unexpected var values.  Always check the result of syscalls. Learn how to use a debugger. Oh - and learn how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 4):

Multiple issues here.

1. After `fclose(score);`, you're trying to use  `fprintf(score,"%d", s);`. Why? Maybe you want to move `fclose(score);` before `return 0`;
2. Always put a success check on the return value of `fopen()`. Also, as per your requirement, `keep on adding score every time the code is run without deleting the last record` you need to `fopen()` in *append* mode. Check more about the *modes* and their usage [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen).
3. `scanf("%s", &n);` is wrong. Here what you want is an array, not a single `char`. Consider changing your `char n;` to `char n[32];` or something. [Note: once `n` is array, change the `scanf()` to `scanf("%s", n);`]
4. `fprintf(score,"%d", n);` is wrong. Do not use incompatible format specifier. for a string, it should be `%s`. *[Even in your case, `n` is `char`. There's no way the format specifier should be `%d`.]*

Comment: and open in append mode: `score = fopen("score.txt", "a");`

Comment: and check if `fopen` returned `NULL`

Comment: @iharob yes sir, already mentioned `Also, always put a success check on the return value of fopen().`:-)

Comment: @P.J.Meisch Good one, but _upto some extent_ based on _our assumption_, isn't it? Let OP decide the mode. :-)

Comment: Also,the `&` should not be added in `scanf("%s",&n);`

Comment: @SouravGhosh False. The OP mentioned "keep on adding score every time the code is run without deleting the last record"

Comment: Right. I stand corrected. Updating answer. @P.J.Meisch

Answer (score 2):

There are few problems with the code given above.

- You need to open the file in append mode, if you need to add the new score without deleting the old one.
- You have to write the score to file before doing an fclose.
- char n can hold only a single char. If your intention is to read a proper name with more characters, you need a char array, like char name[100].

The code given below gives a proper way to append to a file.

```
    FILE *score;
    char name[100];
    int nScore;

// Open the file
    score = fopen("score.txt", "a+");
    if(!score)
    {
        printf("Failed to open");
        return 1;
    }

// Get user inputs
    printf("You got a high score!\nPlease enter score: ");
    scanf("%d", &nScore);
    printf("\nPlease enter your name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);

//Write to file
    fprintf(score, "Name: %s  Score: %d\n", name, nScore);

// Close the file
    fclose(score);
    printf("\nData Stored into score.txt\n");

    return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Note also that the name `n` cannot be stored as a `char`. It must be either a `char []` or a `char *`. This is probably what's causing your crash, though @SouravGhosh is also correct - basically there are (at least) two bugs in your code.

E.g.

```
char n[80]; // or any other reasonable value, or learn dynamic memory allocation
scanf("%s", n);
```

Comment: Two?  I think we can do better than that:(

Comment: @ace keep on searching u will find more bugs also.

Comment: what about `fprintf(score,"%d", n);` ?

Comment: @MartinJames Edited to "at least two"